# file_get_contents() how to fix error "Failed to open stream", "No such file"

Tags: php, https

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my PHP script:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\LOF\Data.php on line 3
>   script:

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/game/by-summoner/20986461/recent?api_key=*key*'));

print_r($json);

?>
```

Note: `*key*` is a replacement for a string in the URL (my API key) and has been hidden for privacy reasons.

I removed the `https://` from the URL to get one error to disappear.

Am I doing something wrong here? Maybe the URL?

Comment: 8815 views and -2 rating?  Someone must find this useful.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The URL is missing the protocol information. PHP thinks it is a filesystem path and tries to access the file at the specified location. However, the location doesn't actually exist in your filesystem and an error is thrown.

You'll need to add `http` or `https` at the beginning of the URL you're trying to get the contents from:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://...'));
```

As for the following error:

> Unable to find the wrapper - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Your Apache installation probably wasn't compiled with SSL support. You could manually try to install OpenSSL and use it, or use cURL. I personally prefer cURL over `file_get_contents()`. Here's a function you can use:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Usage:

```
$url = 'https://...';
$json = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [**`cURL`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ?

```
$yourkey="your api key";
$url="https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/game/by-summoner/20986461/recent?api_key=$yourkey";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$auth = curl_exec($curl);
if($auth)
{
$json = json_decode($auth); 
print_r($json);
}
}
```

Comment: I dont know what cUrl is, i ame kinda new to php sry

Comment: It's just an extension of PHP , you need to enable it. Most probably it would have been enabled by default. Anyways have a look here.. http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

You may try using this

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('./prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/game/by-summoner/20986461/recent?api_key=*key*'));
print_r($json);
?>
```

The "./" allows to search url from current directory.
You may use

```
chdir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

to change current working directory to root of your website if path is relative from root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I just solve this by encode params in the url.
URL may be: `http://abc/dgdc.php?p1=Hello&p2=some words`
we just need to encode the params2.

```php
$params2 = "some words";
$params2 = urlencode($params2);

$url = "http://abc/dgdc.php?p1=djkl&p2=$params2"

$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

just to extend Shankars and amals answers with simple unit testing:

```
/**
 *
 * workaround HTTPS problems with file_get_contents
 *
 * @param $url
 * @return boolean|string
 */
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $data = FALSE;
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $data;
}
// then in the unit tests:
public function test_curl_get_contents()
{
    $this->assertFalse(curl_get_contents(NULL));
    $this->assertFalse(curl_get_contents('foo'));
    $this->assertTrue(strlen(curl_get_contents('https://www.google.com')) > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue by using Curl....

```
function my_curl_fun($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}

$feed = 'http://................'; /* Insert URL here */
$data = my_curl_fun($feed);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem of this error has nothing to do with file_get_content, the problem is the requested url if the url is not throwing content of the page and redirecting the request to some where else file_get_content says "Failed to open stream", just before file_get_contents check whether the url is working and not redirecting, here is the code:

function checkRedirect404($url)
{

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

    // line endings is the wonkiest piece of this whole thing
    $out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

    // only look at the headers
    $headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
    if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
        $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
    }   

    $headers = explode("\n", $out);
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if( substr($header, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
            $target = substr($header, 10);

            //echo "Redirects: $target<br>";

            return true;
        }   
    }   

    return false;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I hope below solution will work for you all as I was having the same problem with my websites...

For :  `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://...'));`

Replace with below query

`$Details= unserialize(file_get_contents('http://......'));`