# file_get_contents How to not show if does not have array needed

Tags: php

I am trying to get my code to work when the url its sent to does not have the variables needed.

this is the error:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(the link): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found -- at line 23

Ex my code goes to this users page and everything okay:

https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/24267598/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803

But when it goes to this users page it gives a error:

https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/77828400/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803

What im after doing if when there is no content in url for it not to show anything and when there is to show it. But for some reason I cant get it to work with both.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'APIKEY';
$summonerName = 'raget deathdex';
$new = rawurlencode($summonerName);

$news = str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName);
$str = strtolower($news);

$result = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $new . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$str;
$id = $summoner->id;
?>  

<?php   
$claw = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $id . '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' . $apiKey);
$gaza = json_decode($claw);
?>

<?php 
$entriesz = $gaza->champions;
usort($entriesz, function($ac,$bc){
    return $bc->stats->totalSessionsPlayed-$ac->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
});

foreach($entriesz as $statSummaryz) if ($tmp++ < 11){

    $getLeagueNamelistside = $statSummaryz->id;
    $getsessionsplayedNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
    $getMiniomskillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalMinionKills;
    $getkillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalChampionKills;
    $getassistssNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalAssists;
    $getdeathsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalDeathsPerSession;
    $getlosseslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsLost;
    $getwinslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsWon;

    $Percentkillrateside = $getkillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
    $Percentassistrateside = $getassistssNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
    $Percentdeathrateside = $getdeathsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
    $KDAside = ($getkillsNamelistside + $getassistssNamelistside) / $getdeathsNamelistside;
    $KDAMinniomsSide = $getMiniomskillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
    $PercentWinRateSide = 100 / ($getlosseslistside + $getwinslistside) * $getwinslistside;

    if ($getLeagueNamelistside >=1){

        $resultz = file_get_contents('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'.$getLeagueNamelistside.'?api_key=' . $apiKey);
        $summonerz = json_decode($resultz, true);
        $getLeagueNamelistsidez = $summonerz['name'];
        $getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez = $summonerz['key'];
        echo '<p><img src="http://lolchecker.esy.es/LOLGGWP/img/champion/' .$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez. '.png"></p>'.$getLeagueNamelistsidez. '<p> Kills '.number_format((float)$Percentkillrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> Deaths '.number_format((float)$Percentdeathrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> Assists '.number_format((float)$Percentassistrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> KDA '.number_format((float)$KDAside, 2, '.', '').':1 KDA</p><p> CS '.number_format((float)$KDAMinniomsSide, 1, '.', '').' CS</p><p> Games Played '.$getsessionsplayedNamelistside.'</p><p> Win Rate '.number_format((float)$PercentWinRateSide, 0, '.', '').'%</p>';

    }
    elseif($getLeagueNamelistside =0){
        return DO_NOTHING;

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: You are using different urls as 1st is `24267598/ranked` & 2nd is  `77828400/ranked`;

Comment: Yes, as they are for different users, what i need the code to do is if it give error like in user 2 not to show anything and if not continues, but cant find away to do that

Comment: Then you should check if `status_code` exists within the object and handle it accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents() how to fix error "Failed to open stream", "No such file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562368/file-get-contents-how-to-fix-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

PHP treats strings like a byte array. Instead of checking if a string is empty of if the strings length is greater than 0, I like to check to see if the first byte is set. Some people consider it less humanly readable, but thats just *some people*.

Use `isset($mystring[0])` to see if a string is at least one character in length.

The `@` symbol before the file_get_contents is for error suppression. The @ prevents an error from appearing in your browser if the file can't be found.

---

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803';
$summonerName = 'raget deathdex';
$new = rawurlencode($summonerName);

$news = str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName);
$str = strtolower($news);


$result = @file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $new . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
if(!isset($result[0])) {
    die(); // die('Nothing found in \'result\' file.');
}

$summoner = json_decode($result)->$str;
if(!$summoner) {
    die(); // die('Nothing found in \'result\' content.');
}

$id = $summoner->id;

?>  



<?php   
$claw = @file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $id . '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' . $apiKey);
if(!isset($claw[0])) {
    die(); // die('Nothing found in \'claw\' file.');
}

$gaza = json_decode($claw);
if(!$gaza) {
    die(); // die('Nothing found in \'claw\' content.');
}
?>


<?php 
$entriesz = $gaza->champions;
usort($entriesz, function($ac,$bc){
return $bc->stats->totalSessionsPlayed-$ac->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
});

foreach($entriesz as $statSummaryz) if ($tmp++ < 11){

$getLeagueNamelistside = $statSummaryz->id;
$getsessionsplayedNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
$getMiniomskillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalMinionKills;
$getkillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalChampionKills;
$getassistssNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalAssists;
$getdeathsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalDeathsPerSession;
$getlosseslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsLost;
$getwinslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsWon;



$Percentkillrateside = $getkillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
$Percentassistrateside = $getassistssNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
$Percentdeathrateside = $getdeathsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
$KDAside = ($getkillsNamelistside + $getassistssNamelistside) / $getdeathsNamelistside;
$KDAMinniomsSide = $getMiniomskillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
$PercentWinRateSide = 100 / ($getlosseslistside + $getwinslistside) * $getwinslistside;


if ($getLeagueNamelistside >=1){

    $resultz = @file_get_contents('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'.$getLeagueNamelistside.'?api_key=' . $apiKey);
    if(!isset($resultz[0])) {
        die(); // die('Nothing found in league file:' . $getLeagueNamelistside);
    }

$summonerz = json_decode($resultz, true);
if(!summonerz) {
    die(); // die('Nothing found in league content:' . $getLeagueNamelistside);
}

$getLeagueNamelistsidez = $summonerz['name'];
$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez = $summonerz['key'];
    echo '<p><img src="http://lolchecker.esy.es/LOLGGWP/img/champion/' .$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez. '.png"></p>'.$getLeagueNamelistsidez. '<p> Kills '.number_format((float)$Percentkillrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> Deaths '.number_format((float)$Percentdeathrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> Assists '.number_format((float)$Percentassistrateside, 1, '.', '').'</p><p> KDA '.number_format((float)$KDAside, 2, '.', '').':1 KDA</p><p> CS '.number_format((float)$KDAMinniomsSide, 1, '.', '').' CS</p><p> Games Played '.$getsessionsplayedNamelistside.'</p><p> Win Rate '.number_format((float)$PercentWinRateSide, 0, '.', '').'%</p>';



}
 elseif($getLeagueNamelistside == 0){
    die();
   }
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803';
$summonerName = 'raget deathdex';

// =====

$results = @file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . rawurlencode($summonerName) . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
if(!isset($results[0]))
    die();

$summoner = json_decode($results)->strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName));
if(!$summoner)
    die();

$results = @file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $summoner->id . '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' . $apiKey);
if(!isset($results[0]))
    die();

$gaza = json_decode($results);
if(!$gaza)
    die();

// =====

$entriesz = $gaza->champions;
usort($entriesz, function($ac, $bc){
    return $bc->stats->totalSessionsPlayed-$ac->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
});

// =====

foreach($entriesz as $statSummaryz) {
    if($tmp++ < 11) {
        $getLeagueNamelistside = $statSummaryz->id;
        $getsessionsplayedNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
        $getMiniomskillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalMinionKills;
        $getkillsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalChampionKills;
        $getassistssNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalAssists;
        $getdeathsNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalDeathsPerSession;
        $getlosseslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsLost;
        $getwinslistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsWon;

        $Percentkillrateside = $getkillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
        $Percentassistrateside = $getassistssNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
        $Percentdeathrateside = $getdeathsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
        $KDAside = ($getkillsNamelistside + $getassistssNamelistside) / $getdeathsNamelistside;
        $KDAMinniomsSide = $getMiniomskillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
        $PercentWinRateSide = 100 / ($getlosseslistside + $getwinslistside) * $getwinslistside;

        if($getLeagueNamelistside >= 1) {
            $results = @file_get_contents('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/' . $getLeagueNamelistside . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
            if(!isset($results[0]))
                die();
        }

        $summonerz = json_decode($results, true);
        if(!$summonerz)
            die();

        $getLeagueNamelistsidez = $summonerz['name'];
        $getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez = $summonerz['key'];
        echo 
            '<p><img src="http://lolchecker.esy.es/LOLGGWP/img/champion/', $getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez, '.png"></p>',
            $getLeagueNamelistsidez,
            '<p> Kills ', number_format((float)$Percentkillrateside, 1, '.', ''),
            '</p><p> Deaths ', number_format((float)$Percentdeathrateside, 1, '.', ''),
            '</p><p> Assists ', number_format((float)$Percentassistrateside, 1, '.', ''),
            '</p><p> KDA ', number_format((float)$KDAside, 2, '.', ''),
            ':1 KDA</p><p> CS ', number_format((float)$KDAMinniomsSide, 1, '.', ''),
            ' CS</p><p> Games Played ', $getsessionsplayedNamelistside,
            '</p><p> Win Rate ', number_format((float)$PercentWinRateSide, 0, '.', ''),
            '%</p>', "\n";
    }
    elseif($getLeagueNamelistside == 0)
        die();
}
```

Comment: Gives error                       Line : 11,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: But im looking for if it does not exists dont post what is in the ECHO, so nothing shows on screen then

Comment: Try it now. I haven't actually tested this myself. There was just some brackets missing thanks to notepad++.

Comment: I left die messages in there just so you can see whats going on. If you want it to display nothing, just change those functions to die();

Comment: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant DO_NOTHING - assumed 'DO_NOTHING' -- at line 86

Comment: Says that, im not great at php but learning , thanks for your help :)

Comment: You must not have defined DO_NOTHING. Instead of using return since were not in a function, we can just die(); there too. =)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the file contents in order to determine it has the required data.

```
<?php   
$claw = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $id . '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' . $apiKey);
if(false === empty($claw)) {
    $gaza = json_decode($claw);
    if(true === empty($gaza->champion)) {
        return 'Invalid data received';
    }
} else {
    return 'No data found';
}
?>
```

It also looks like you have a syntax error on your comparison condition which is using an assignment operator which will always evaluate to true. But unsure if that portion of your code is used or not.

```
elseif($getLeagueNamelistside =0){
```

Should just be

```
else {
```

which will function as `if ($getLeagueNamelistside <= 0) return DO_NOTHING;`

---

**UPDATE**

To prevent the file not found error, and others from being displayed, you can disable the display of error messages. Which should be the case in production code anyways.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

Or filter the display of only certain error messages.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

You can also bypass error reporting of specific commands by prepending `@`

```
@file_get_contents('https://example.com/index.php');
```

Last but not least, and my preferred method, is to use output buffering to prevent undesired content from outputting to the client.

```
ob_start();
echo file_get_contents('https://example.com/index.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
echo false === strpos($content, '404') ? $content : 'OOps';
```

Comment: Still shows this warning :                                                                                      E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/77828400/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found -- at line 24

Comment: That makes more sense - I see you updated your question with that error message.  Was attempting to handle the parsing of the json content with the 404 response instead of handling `file_get_contents` Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
$news = str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName);
$str  = strtolower($news);

$result   = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $new . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$str;
$id       = $summoner->id;

$claw = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $id . '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' . $apiKey);
$gaza = json_decode($claw);
if (isset($gaza->champions)) {
  $entriesz = $gaza->champions;
  usort($entriesz, function($ac, $bc) {
    return $bc->stats->totalSessionsPlayed - $ac->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
  });

  foreach ($entriesz as $statSummaryz) {
    if ($tmp++ < 11) {
      $getLeagueNamelistside         = $statSummaryz->id;
      $getsessionsplayedNamelistside = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsPlayed;
      $getMiniomskillsNamelistside   = $statSummaryz->stats->totalMinionKills;
      $getkillsNamelistside          = $statSummaryz->stats->totalChampionKills;
      $getassistssNamelistside       = $statSummaryz->stats->totalAssists;
      $getdeathsNamelistside         = $statSummaryz->stats->totalDeathsPerSession;
      $getlosseslistside             = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsLost;
      $getwinslistside               = $statSummaryz->stats->totalSessionsWon;

      $Percentkillrateside   = $getkillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
      $Percentassistrateside = $getassistssNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
      $Percentdeathrateside  = $getdeathsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
      $KDAside               = ($getkillsNamelistside + $getassistssNamelistside) / $getdeathsNamelistside;
      $KDAMinniomsSide       = $getMiniomskillsNamelistside / $getsessionsplayedNamelistside;
      $PercentWinRateSide    = 100 / ($getlosseslistside + $getwinslistside) * $getwinslistside;

      if ($getLeagueNamelistside >= 1) {
        $resultz                   = file_get_contents('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/' . $getLeagueNamelistside . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
        $summonerz                 = json_decode($resultz, true);
        $getLeagueNamelistsidez    = $summonerz['name'];
        $getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez = $summonerz['key'];
        echo '<p><img src="http://lolchecker.esy.es/LOLGGWP/img/champion/' . $getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez . '.png"></p>' . $getLeagueNamelistsidez . '<p> Kills ' . number_format((float) $Percentkillrateside, 1, '.', '') . '</p><p> Deaths ' . number_format((float) $Percentdeathrateside, 1, '.', '') . '</p><p> Assists ' . number_format((float) $Percentassistrateside, 1, '.', '') . '</p><p> KDA ' . number_format((float) $KDAside, 2, '.', '') . ':1 KDA</p><p> CS ' . number_format((float) $KDAMinniomsSide, 1, '.', '') . ' CS</p><p> Games Played ' . $getsessionsplayedNamelistside . '</p><p> Win Rate ' . number_format((float) $PercentWinRateSide, 0, '.', '') . '%</p>';
      } elseif ($getLeagueNamelistside == 0) {
        return DO_NOTHING;
      }
    }
  }
}
```