# file_get_contents converts & to &amp; in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

There are many similar posts but none of them explain the issue cause and recommend to use curl instead.

I found strange thing when developing one Wordpress plugin. This plugin needs to call API and I am doing it like this

```
file_get_contents( 'foo&bar' );
```

For some reason the & in there is encoded to & and error log shows

```
file_get_contents(foo&amp;bar): failed to open stream
```

However while testing on commandline on same machine I see no encoding with same code

```
<?php
file_get_contents('foo&bar');


file_get_contents(foo&bar): failed to open stream
```

Which flags or settings make the difference in behavior?

```
file_get_contents(foo&amp;bar): failed to open stream
vs
file_get_contents(foo&bar): failed to open stream

$ php -v
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

Comment: Is the file_get_contents param a valid url? Check this possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562368/file-get-contents-how-to-fix-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file

Comment: URL is intentionally invalid. It is just for testing purposes something that contains & sign.

Comment: URL with parameters works fine with `file_get_contents` and the *failed to open stream* is clear here, try a valid URL with params, it should work

Comment: Issue is conversion of & to &amp; not the invalid url

Comment: Here is an answer which shows how to suppress, handle errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php . If you're trying to do something different than what file_get_contents is made for, then you must create your own function which will use cURL

Comment: Per chance, is the first log output from the browser? If so, I believe it is converted to &amp during the error display so it can be displayed in browser. The request itself is still using "&";

Comment: Encoded error is from apache error log. Unencoded is from console output